# Compiling with .jars results in missing .class files

Tags: java, ant, jar

When writing my projects, I use a number of apis and libraries. The projects compile - I have added the .jars to my classpath - however, the relevant .class files are not added to the final jar. Is there a way to force this? I'm not using an IDE like Eclipse (and would honestly prefer not to).

Answer (score 1):

No, the classes aren't *meant* to be added to your jar file. Instead, the idea is that you supply the 3rd party jar files alongside your own jar file. If you *really* need to only have one jar file, you'd need to merge all the jar files together - but I'd strongly recommend that you don't do this unless it's absolutely vital. (You'll need to work out how to merge the manifests etc).

Comment: That's what I thought... what do you recommend?

Comment: Do you need to supply a self-contained jar?

Comment: @TylerSebastian: I recommend that you supply your code in one jar, and the third-party jars as they are.

Comment: @JonSkeet not currently - how would i reference/point to these third-party jars in my project?

Comment: @TylerSebastian: I don't know what you mean. We have no idea what you mean by "project" given that you've said you're not using an IDE. You need to give us more information about how you're trying to run your app - you should just be able to specify the classpath to include all the jar files.

Comment: @JonSkeet It's a server java plugin (MineCraft). My classpath contains all relevant .jars.

Comment: @TylerSebastian: If the classpath contains the jar files, then why would you expect the class files to be added to *your* jar? They don't need to be - the classes just need to be present in the classpath.